# Read specific folder's name from folder's path Python

Tags: python, parsing, directory

I'm trying to read the folder name at the specific place from the file path. My current code:

```
import os

# search for and input multiple files 
def get_files(source):
    matches = []
    for root, dirnames, filenames in os.walk(source):
        for filename in filenames:
            matches.append(os.path.join(root, filename))
    return matches

def parse(files):
    for file in files:
        xml_information = {}
        metadata = []
        # Get the file path
        filepath = os.path.dirname(file)
        xml_information['file_path'] = '%s' % filepath
        
        # Get customer name
        customer = filepath.split("\\")[5]
        xml_information['customer_name'] = '%s' % customer
        metadata.append(xml_information)
        print(metadata)

path = 'C:\\Users\\quan.nguyen\\SAGE\\Lania Thompson - Searching Project Files'

parse(get_files(path))
```

My program searches through folders and find the files and report back their folder path. However, I would like to read the folder path as well as the folder name at the sixth place which is customer name. When I run `customer = filepath.split("\\")[5]` it report an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "*hidden*", line 33, in <module>
    parse(get_files(path))
  File "*hidden*", line 26, in parse
    customer = filepath.split("\\")[5]
               ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^^^
IndexError: list index out of range
```

However, when I run with `customer = filepath.split("\\")[4]`, the program works and reads the last folder specified in `path` which is Lania Thompson - Searching Project Files. The result is as follows:

```
[{'file_path': 'C:\\Users\\quan.nguyen\\SAGE\\Lania Thompson - Searching Project Files\\Hazor Ltd\\PCS Mah\\Machine', 'customer_name': 'Lania Thompson - Searching Project Files'}]
```

My expecting result is Hazor Ltd:

```
[{'file_path': 'C:\\Users\\quan.nguyen\\SAGE\\Lania Thompson - Searching Project Files\\Hazor Ltd\\PCS Mah\\Machine', 'customer_name': 'Hazor Ltd'}]
```

The names are made up except from my name

Comment: Array indexes start at 0. `[5]` means the 6th element of the list.

Comment: It would be better to use functions that parse pathnames for this, like `pathlib` or `os.path.basename()`.

Comment: If you want the last element of a list, use `[-1]`. Negative indexes count from the end.

Comment: raw string would help here, stick a `r` in front of the open quote like this `path = r'C:\Users\quan.nguyen\SAGE\Lania Thompson - Searching Project Files'`. You should be using a tool made for this as Barmar suggested, but fyi you can index from the back of a list with negative values. `[-1]` gets you the last element of a list

Comment: Unless you made up these names, I would edit the question to not include actual client's names and data - they might not enjoy finding it on StackOverflow.

Comment: Yes, the names are made up except my name and company name.

Comment: The reading backward isn't working for me since most files have different file path to read. Only at the sixth place of the file path reading forward is constant which is the customer name.
I have tried putting a ```r``` in front the path but does not fix the problem.
I will see how the pathlib works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I have worked out the code. The code is:

```
import os

# search for and input multiple files 
def get_files(source):
    matches = []
    for root, dirnames, filenames in os.walk(source):
        for filename in filenames:
            matches.append(os.path.join(root, filename))
    return matches

def parse(files):
    for file in files:
        # Get the file path
        absolutefilepath = os.path.abspath(file)
        filepath = os.path.dirname(absolutefilepath)
        try:
            parts = filepath.split(os.sep)
            customer = parts[1]
            print(customer)
        except:
            continue

path = 'C:\\Users\\quan.nguyen\\SAGE\\Lania Thompson - Searching Project Files'

parse(get_files(path))
```

change the number `[5]` in `xml_information['Customer'] = f.parts[5]` for the place you want to get the folder's name from. Try and except is there so that if the folder at the specified location does not exist then continue the loop.